# Strange linker error in cpp

Tags: c++, windows, linker-errors

When I add the following line to my code:

```
std::string sFrameTag
```

I get the following linker error:

```
Error   34  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct 
std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?
$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in 
VFPAnalyzerApi.lib(VFPEvaluation.obj)   msvcprtd.lib
```

I'm sure `sFrameTag` is only defined once, I tried using other names for this variable to be sure. I have the following includes: `stdio.h`, `time.h`, `string`.

Can someone please guide it as to what causes this error?

Comment: Please show us the actual line you added to your code (and maybe some of the code, if it isn't 100+ lines). It can't be `std::string sFrameTag`, that's missing at least a semicolon, and I suspect there are a few parantheses or other stuff as well.

Comment: See http://www.cegui.org.uk/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=5445

Comment: You may show more detail, incuding the file you define in, and others.

Comment: sounds like you are linking the same lib twice

Comment: Since the multiply defined symbol is the std::string destructor I don't see how the code can be to blame. The error is in the compiler/linker/project settings, or maybe the way in which VFPAnalyzerApi.lib was built.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a static instead of dynamic library?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 

Here is the first lines of the function:

void VFPEvaluation::appendMultSteamStatfile(VFPFrameData imData) 
{ 
 char str[256],matchTag[256],matchRef[256];
 sipl_bool isResMatch = imData.matchResult;
 sipl_bool isRefMatch;
 char refStream[256];
 char chosenStream[256];

 std::string XXXFrameTag; 
 


Once I add the line "std::string XXXFrameTag;", I get the linker errors I wrote above and also "LNK1169 lnk1169 one or more multiply defined".

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I'm not really sure how to modify my code so it will link. Is there anything I need to change in the project settings?


Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too get similar kind of errors when I tried to statically include all needed runtime libraries. Do check that when you are trying to import a library which is linked statically with /MD option you also need to use /MD.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: Thanks Niraj, but can you please explain what exactly I need to do? I'm not sure how to use /MD..


Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @user2215359 It depnds on which version of VC++ you are using. But on my version the relavent options are under Project Properties - C/C++ - Code Generation - Runtime Library

Comment: OK, so I took a look at the project properties, under C/C++ -> code generation -> runtime Library and changed it from /MDd to /MD and now it works!!! 


Thanks!! 

But, can someone please explain what exactly is the meaning of this change? thanks in advance.